# Проверка пользователя ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

Есть кнопка в игре "Купить". При нажатии на неё через Ajax отправляются данные о юзере (Id, имя) и обрабатываются далее php скриптом (снимается баланс, начисляется товар).
Вопрос: как проверить подлиность юзера? Тот ли юзер отправляет запрос, а не поддельный ли он? 
Как я понял нужно посылать дополнительно какой-то хэш зашифрованый и проверять его в том же скрипте.

Comment: юзер то у вас авторизован? вот и берите его id из сессии, а не из запроса

Comment: Да авторизован, но к примеру запрос легко подделать. Я авторизованный шлю ID не свой, а к примеру другого человека. Как итог - покупка совершается у другого игрока...

Comment: дак я вам и пишу, что не надо брать ID который шлют, надо брать ID который вы храните в сессии

Comment: А как в обработчике php сессию проверить, если только послать. Но опять же, тогда её можно подделать)

Comment: а как вы авторизуете пользователя вообще, если спрашиваете, как проверить ?

Comment: Проверяю логин и пароль, присваиваю сессию. А вот как передаётся сессия через ajax - непонятно...

Comment: идентификатор сессии передается с куками в каждом запросе. при обработке аякс запроса на стороне пхп вы все так же стартуете сессию и считываете оттуда ID пользователя.

Comment: Боже, я этого не знал. Всё оказалось проще) Спасибо вам большое, что потратили время на меня.